# Convert the latest data pull of a raw Variant table into a normal table: Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a variant table where raw json data is stored in a column called "raw" as shown here.

[image]

Each row of this table is a full data pull from an API and ingested via snowpipe. Within the json there is a 'pxQueryTimestamp' key and value pair. The latest value for this field should have the most up to date data. How would I go about only normalizing this row?

Usually my way around this, is to only pipe over the latest data from "s3" so that this table has only one row, then I normalize that.

I'd like to have a historic table of all data pulls as show below but when normalizing we only care about the most relevant up to date data.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: how is this data ordered? as in can you assume the first/last record is always going to be the newest one? because otherwise all you have left is querying the JSON, and this isn't going to be the cheapest operation you can imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that you want to flatten and retain everything in the most current variant record, then I'd suggest leveraging a STREAM object in Snowflake, which would then only have the latest variant record.  You could then TRUNCATE your flattened table and run an insert from the STREAM object to your flattened table, which would then move the offset forward and your STREAM would then be empty.

Take a look at the documentation here:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/streams.html

Comment: Can you truncate the flattened table only if the stream has data? I would not want to truncate the flattened table if there is no insert object from the stream.

Comment: Yes, you can use the SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA function to determine that, and you can conditionally use that in a TASK if you want to use tasks to automate the process.

Comment: This worked perfectly, is there any other neat tips I could do? Maybe only create the new table if there is new rows or updated rows? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: That would be a lot more complicated, because you'd need to flatten it in order to compare the tables to see if anything has changed.  Probably not worth the effort compared to the amount of work its taking to flatten and recreate the table each time.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I appreciate the feed back, it might be more advantageous for me to handle this with python in AWS lambda.

Comment: If you just let it run every time you have new data, regardless of whether there are changes, it'd probably be pretty fast compared to python.  Look into the INSERT WITH OVERWRITE option, rather than a TRUNCATE and then INSERT.  This will provide no downtime while the data is being flattened and loaded.